# May "by the way" be used in formal professional writing?

Tags: expressions, politeness

I saw many times on forums or chats discussions the expression `by the way`.

I understood its meaning, but is it a familiar expression or could I use in professional documents or messages?

If it is not, what kind of expression would be similar but polite?

Comment: A few similar expressions: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/american/ways-of-adding-extra-information.

Comment: You can check the [ELU answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33793/by-the-way-in-formal-writing) regarding your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Professionally people do not use this. Some other alternatives are:

- In addition
- Furthermore
- As well
- Moreover

Answer (score 6):

'Incidentally' could be the perfect formal substitute for 'by the way'.